# Saving a MS Excel 2010 file that not let you to copy data from it?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I know how to protect an Excel file with password for opening it, but is it possible to save an Excel 2010 file as a file that not let you to copy data from it, **only** reading it?

Comment: If you can read it, you can copy it.

Comment: Isn't there something like in PDF files in which you can protect file from copying and it's available for reading?

Comment: If you think a PDF will work for you, then why not save it as a PDF using Excel's in-built PDF saving features?  Regardless, my original statement covers ANY file type (and beyond), including PDF files. Perhaps you could export it (somehow) out as an Image, rendering the text un-selectable as "text", but OCR works pretty good these days.  At best you could spend a bunch of your time developing a solution that will only slow someone down slightly, but you'll never stop them from copying it if they really want it.  But hey, perhaps someone will come up with a satisfactory answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want editing OR text selection, then your best bet would be to screen-capture or some other image export option.

Obviously this doesn't prevent someone from just manually entering the information by hand into another workbook, but that's not a solvable problem unless you also administer the machine that your audience is using to view the file.

Comment: Even then, they could just copy it into a paper notebook with a pencil. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I do know that, at the end, it's useless. Just need to find a way to do it in Excel because my boss asked me that, and he is not an IT guy.

Comment: Yeah exactly.  And I wouldn't bother with that either, I'd just take a screenshot with my camera phone and OCR that.  But s/he's looking for non-selectable text, so, there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Although it will always be possible for someone looking at the data to just open another Excel sheet and copy it manually, there is a way to [disable the toolbar and shortcuts using macros](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-excel/1002003-protect-my-excel-file-beeing-copied.html#post3692242). This may not work if the file is opened with an older version of Excel or a viewer which doesn't support macros. Just my two cents.